# Quick ways to fill the missing values of a pandas dataframe with complicated rules

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment

In the m*(n+1) pandas dataframe `data_df`, there is a `timestamp` column whose values are possibly repeated integers in `range(0,p)` (which denote time; there are p unique values in total) and no missing values. There are other columns `data_1`, `data_2`, `data_3`, ... `data_n`, each with some missing values.

I would like to fill the missing values in each row of the data columns using specific numbers with respect to the `timestamp` value of that row. Therefore, I obtained a p*n pandas dataframe `median_table`. The values on the ith row of `median_table` are used to fill the missing values in `data_df` whose `timestamp` is i.

However, I could not come up with a quick and memory-friendly way to do this. Currently, I use the following code (`median_table` and `data_df` are already defined):

```
new_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
for _timestamp in median_table.timestamp:
    temp_df = data_df.loc[data_df.timestamp == _timestamp]
    temp_df.fillna(median_table.loc[_timestamp, :], inplace=True)
    new_data_df = new_data_df.append(temp_df)
```

which is extremely inefficient. Another algorithm:

```
for _timestamp in median_table.timestamp:
    data_df.loc[data_df.timestamp == _timestamp] = \
        data_df.loc[data_df.timestamp == _timestamp]\
            .fillna(median_table.loc[_timestamp, :], inplace=False)
```

worked equally slowly for me.

Is there a quicker way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: Identify NaNs in `data_df` and merge those with your `median_table`. I'd expect that to be faster than a for-loop. Apologies if I've incorrectly assumed the structure of your data, but this may at least get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dummy dataframe
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "data": [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan]
    })
print data_df
"""
Dataframe looks like:
data  timestamp
 1.0          1
 2.0          2
 NaN          3
 NaN          4
"""

# Create dummy median table
median_table = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "missing_data": [100, 200, 300, 400]
    })
print median_table
"""
Median table looks like:
missing_data  timestamp
    100          1
    200          2
    300          3
    400          4
"""

# Find NaNs in "data" column in data_df
nan_indexes = data_df["data"].isnull()
nan_df = data_df[nan_indexes]
print nan_df
"""
nan_df looks like:
data  timestamp
 NaN          3
 NaN          4
"""

# Merge nan_df with median_table based on timestamp column
new_df = pd.merge(left=nan_df, right=median_table, on="timestamp", how="left")
print new_df
"""
new_df looks like:
data  timestamp  missing_data
 NaN          3           300
 NaN          4           400
"""

# Clean up new_df
new_df = new_df[["timestamp", "missing_data"]]  # Discard "data" column
new_df.columns = ["timestamp", "data"]  # Rename "missing_data" column to "data"
print new_df
"""
new_df now looks like:
timestamp  data
 3   300
 4   400
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I just realized that using the `DataFrame.groupby()` method rather than creating a new median table in the very beginning could be very effective.